# Associate an Azure DataFactory pipeline to a billing report

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there any way to label the DataFactory pipelines so you can see the invoice and associate the cost with a particular use case?

Or does some other alternative that helps to fulfill this purpose exist?

Comment: Hi CPR, welcome to Stack Overflow,  If the answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid we can't achieve that.

We only can see the cost details for each  Service Resource in Data Factory per month:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!